# Writing to excel using Apache poi(Error)

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi, export-to-excel

I'm writing data into excel file using `Apache Poi` In `Java Eclipse`,Problem is when i add column aligned with each row,it override the previous column...here is the code before i add anything.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); 

      XSSFSheet spreadsheet = workbook.createSheet("cellstyle");

      XSSFRow row=spreadsheet.createRow(1);
      XSSFCell cell;

      row = spreadsheet.createRow((short) 4);
      row.setHeight((short) 800);
      cell = (XSSFCell) row.createCell((short) 5);
      cell.setCellValue("Total Alerts raised");

      spreadsheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(4,4,5,6));


      row = spreadsheet.createRow(5);
      cell = (XSSFCell) row.createCell(5);
      cell.setCellValue("Critical"); 

      row = spreadsheet.createRow(6);
      cell = (XSSFCell) row.createCell(5);
      cell.setCellValue("Warning"); 

      row = spreadsheet.createRow(7);
      cell = (XSSFCell) row.createCell(5);
      cell.setCellValue("Total"); 




      FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(
      new File("C:\\Users\\tshivhaser\\Desktop\\cellstyle.xlsx"));
      workbook.write(out);
      out.close();
      System.out.println("cellstyle.xlsx written successfully");

}
```

I then add this piece of code...Critical,Warning and Total column becomes empty

```
      row = spreadsheet.createRow(5);
      cell =  row.createCell(6);
      cell.setCellValue(0); 

      row = spreadsheet.createRow(6);
      cell = row.createCell(6);
      cell.setCellValue(0); 

      row = spreadsheet.createRow(7);
      cell =  row.createCell(6);
      cell.setCellValue(10);
```

Please help on how i can have all cells filled...

Comment: `createRow` does exactly what it says. It creates a **new** **empty** row. If you have a row already, the you need to **get** the row using [getRow](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#getRow%28int%29). There is [CellUtil](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/util/CellUtil.html) to simplify this having `getRow` method which "Get a row from the spreadsheet, and create it if it doesn't exist.".

Comment: Thanks it worked,but when i implement it in my servlet it throws java.lang.NullPointerException pointing to "cell =  row.createCell(6)"

Comment: Then `row` is null. As documented [Sheet.getRow](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#getRow%28int%29) returns "Row representing the rownumber or **null** if its not defined on the sheet". Please check whether `row` is null after `getRow` and if, **then** create it. Or read about `CellUtil`.